# deezer-ios adding static library

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

I'm trying to use the iOS SDK provided by Deezer to develop an iPhone application. I downloaded the framework [here](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios).

I started a new projet on Xcode (xcode 3.2.6), then I imported all the headers files (and the pics in Resources). Then I made right click on Frameworks and chose "add > add existing framework" and selected the "libDeezer.a" provided by deezer.

I wrote some code in my application delegate class, and when I try to build and run the project I got one warning and one error :

```
ld: warning: in /Users/.../deezer-ios-sdk-0.5 3/deezer-ios-0.5/libDeezer.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DeezerConnect", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref-to-DeezerConnect in deezer5AppDelegate.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I link the library to my project? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Double click on project target, and in the search path group, there is a attribute called Library Search path. please specify the path correctly.

if you have still doubt let me know , i will specify more

Comment: I did it, and i still got the errors. http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/8315/capturedcran20120523153.png

Comment: Could it be the libDeezer.a provided by Deezer responsible for this issue ? Since i got the warning "missing required architecture i386 in file"

Answer (score 1):

Are you building for simulator or device ?
The Deezer's iOS SDK is not working on simulator, but devices only.